# при отправке json на api laravel получаю ошибку 404

Tags: json, laravel, post

Ситуация следующая:
Есть api.php

```
Route::post('/test1', 'App\Http\Controllers\ResponseController@response');
```

Контроллер

```
class ResponseController extends Controller
{

    public function response(Request $request)
    {
      echo "Done";
    }
}
```

Из Postman отправляю методом POST

```
{
    "name" : "John",
    "age": 20
}
```

Хотел сначала проверить, работает ли получение JSON. Но возвращается ошибка 404.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть причина?

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался.
Ситуация в том, что я в Postman не правильно указал ссылку, пропустил /api.